Extend Search Functionally to Search in Selected Post Meta
I'm struggling with getting wordpress to extend search custom post meta. I've looked all over the internet and can't seem to find anything that will work. I found one plugin that works, but I don't want to use a plugin.
like this plugin
I'd be very appreciated if someone could write me or point me in the right direction.
Here's my current code:
function searchfilter($query) { if(!is_admin()){ if ($query->is_search) {$query->set('post_type',array('series','movies','concerts'));}return $query;}}add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');

